# Calling react-hook-form trigger method manually disables automatic re-validation on onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

The following code is just a demo for using `trigger` manually, I know it's a simple example, you could use `handleSubmit()` here, but this is just an example.

```
import { z } from 'zod'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { Button, Container, FormControl, FormHelperText, Stack, TextField } from '@mui/material'

const demoSchema = z.object({
  fieldA: z.string().min(2),
})

type DemoFields = z.infer<typeof demoSchema>

function App() {
  const {
    watch,
    trigger,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<DemoFields>({ resolver: zodResolver(demoSchema) })

  const submitHandler = (data: DemoFields) => console.log(data)

  const alt = async () => {
    const isOk = await trigger('fieldA')
    console.log(isOk)
    if (isOk) submitHandler(watch())
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Stack>
        <FormControl error={!!errors.fieldA}>
          <TextField label="Username" {...register('fieldA')} />
          <FormHelperText>{errors.fieldA?.message}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
        <Button onClick={alt} variant="contained">
          Submit!
        </Button>
        <pre>{watch('fieldA')}</pre>
      </Stack>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default App
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yq4gab?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

If I write "h" in the input field, and then I click on the "Submit!" button, of course I see a validation error, and the error message gets printed on the screen:

[image]

This is good. however, the normal behavior of react-hook-form now is I have to click on the "Submit!" button again to get rid of the red error message.

- Does using `trigger()` make everything from now on manual? Is that documented anywhere?
- I want the normal react-hook-form behavior to happen, so that when I write inside the input field, the error goes away as I type correctly.

Comment: Pass `mode: 'onChange'` to useForm `const { watch, trigger, register, formState: { errors }, } = useForm<DemoFields>({ resolver: zodResolver(demoSchema), mode:'onChange' })`

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique, it solves the problem. but now, it will become an error even before submitting

Answer (score 0):

The trigger function manually triggers validation for the specified field(s) but doesn't automatically re-trigger validation as you type.

To achieve real-time validation as the user types, you should use the **useForm** hook to get the **handleSubmit** function, and apply it to the form. This function will automatically trigger validation on each input change. Here's how you can modify your code.  [Preview](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-txtxrb?file=src%2FApp.tsx) in **stackblitz**:

```
import { z } from 'zod';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import {
  Button,
  Container,
  FormControl,
  FormHelperText,
  Stack,
  TextField,
} from '@mui/material';

const demoSchema = z.object({
  fieldA: z.string().min(2),
});

type DemoFields = z.infer<typeof demoSchema>;

export function App() {
  const {
    handleSubmit, // Use handleSubmit from react-hook-form
    watch,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<DemoFields>({ resolver: zodResolver(demoSchema) });

  const submitHandler = (data: DemoFields) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Stack>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}>
          <FormControl error={!!errors.fieldA}>
            <TextField label="Username" {...register('fieldA')} />
            <FormHelperText>{errors.fieldA?.message}</FormHelperText>
          </FormControl>
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
            Submit!
          </Button>
        </form>
        <pre>{watch('fieldA')}</pre>
      </Stack>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Wrapping your input elements in a **form** element and utilizing **handleSubmit** from react-hook-form enables automatic real-time validation on each input change, eliminating the need for manual validation triggers using **trigger**.

Comment: The idea is, I needed to use trigger because I have a multi-step form. of course I should rely on handle submit in this simple example - but on the first line in the question I mentioned that